# How to fetch Email-Ids of people in gplus circle on Android using gplus api?

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus, google-api-java-client, google-signin

I am sing G+ login api in my android app, and i am stuck with how to fetch Email-Ids of people in gplus circle on Android using gplus api.

I have already retrieve a collection of people who are connected to logged-in user as per [this link](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people)

But i am not able to get emails of people in user's circle. so that i can send them invite mail from my app.

Comment: Can you add some sample code indicating how you're doing the request now and what scopes you're requesting.